# How can i filter images based on an input

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a website for students to help them find books that will help them, and I made picture links of  the books, and I tried to filter the images based on the input but I can't, so far this is what I've done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(){
                window.prompt("test")
            }
        const books = [
        {
            name: 'Tonguc',
            id: 'ton',
        },
        {
            name: 'Nitelik',
            id: 'Nitelik',
        },
        {
            name: 'Supara',
            id: 'Supara'
        },
        ]

const correctNameBooks = books.filter(book => book.name === test);
console.log(correctNameBooks) 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn" onclick="test()">test</button>
        <img id="ton" src="img/tonguc.PNG">
        <img id="Nitelik" src="img/nitelik.PNG">
        <img id="Supara" src="img/supara.PNG">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must put the result entered in the prompt window in your `test` variable, and so you can use this value in your filter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function test() {
        const test = window.prompt("test");
        const correctNameBooks = books.filter(book => book.name === test);
        console.log(correctNameBooks);
    }

    const books = [
        {
            name: 'Tonguc',
            id: 'ton',
        },
        {
            name: 'Nitelik',
            id: 'Nitelik',
        },
        {
            name: 'Supara',
            id: 'Supara'
        },
    ]

</script>
</head>

  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="test()">test</button>
    <img id="ton" src="img/tonguc.PNG">
    <img id="Nitelik" src="img/nitelik.PNG">
    <img id="Supara" src="img/supara.PNG">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that I can think of is that you print the images in your script